# Simulate / bypass the following: File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, web

I know this message is telling me the problem... but I'm just messing around with a small fun project and would like to remove the extra click that's required to open a file input when the page loads.

The following (and jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qu52ksef/)

```
<label id="foo" for="input">Open</label>
<input id="input" name="input" type="file">

<script>
    ready(function() {
        document.querySelector("#foo").click();
    });

    function ready(fn) {
        if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
                fn();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will fire the following in Chrome: File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation.

Is there anyway to by pass this check as a sort of 'hack'?. This won't be going into production just a little pet project I'm playing with.

Thanks,

Comment: No you won't be able to do that

Comment: @CodeManiac Worth a shot, good to know.